# How to make tableView scrollable in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiscrollview

I have a UITableView which uses self sizing cells. Now the problem is the cell height is getting changed according to the content size but it is not scrollable. How can I make it Scrollable in Swift.items is a String array of 5 elements. This is my code. As far as I have read the documentation tableviews should be automatically scrollable. But I can only see the first two items and half of the third item. Here is the source code of Project [Dropbox Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aj2jfto7f6t2xnk/tabledynamicfinal.zip?dl=0)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate {
let basicCellIdentifier = "BasicCell"
var items = ["admksalmdlsamdlsamdlkasmdlasmdlsamdlksamdlkasmdlkasmdlksamdklasmdlkasmdlkasmdlkasmdcjkndscnksndcdkcnksdjcnksdnckjsdncsdnjkanckjanckjsnckjasncjkasnckjasncjkasnckdslnjcvlkjdncjsnjkasncjkasncjkasnckjasncjkasnckjsanckjsanckjasncjksancjksancjksancjkasncjasncjkasncklas;NKCNDJKVALNVJKSDANCKSCNJSNCJKSDCNKJSDNCKJANCDKNLSACNJDKCNJKNCAKJNACJKNKJANCKJSNC","badmksalmdlsamdlsamdlkasmdlasmdlsamdlksamdlkasmdlkasmdlksamdklasmdlkasmdlkasmdlkasmdcjkndscnksndcdkcnksdjcnksdnckjsdncsdnjkanckjanckjsnckjasncjkasnckjasncjkasnckdslnjcvlkjdncjsnjkasncjkasncjkasnckjasncjkasnckjsanckjsanckjasncjksancjksancjksancjkasncjasncjkasncklas;NKCNDJKVALNVJKSDANCKSCNJSNCJKSDCNKJSDNCKJANCDKNLSACNJDKCNJKNCAKJNACJKNKJANCKJSNC", "cadmksalmdlsamdlsamdlkasmdlasmdlsamdlksamdlkasmdlkasmdlksamdklasmdlkasmdlkasmdlkasmdcjkndscnksndcdkcnksdjcnksdnckjsdncsdnjkanckjanckjsnckjasncjkasnckjasncjkasnckdslnjcvlkjdncjsnjkasncjkasncjkasnckjasncjkasnckjsanckjsanckjasncjksancjksancjksancjkasncjasncjkasncklas;NKCNDJKVALNVJKSDANCKSCNJSNCJKSDCNKJSDNCKJANCDKNLSACNJDKCNJKNCAKJNACJKNKJANCKJSNCSDNSAJKDNAKLSMDLAKSDMKLASMDLKASMDLKASMDLKASMDLKASMDLKASMDLKASMDLKASMDLKASMDLKASMLAKSMDLASMDLAKSMDLKASMDLKASMDLKASMLKADSMLKASMDLKASMDLKMadmksalmdlsamdlsamdlkasmdlasmdlsamdlksamdlkasmdlkasmdlksamdklasmdlkasmdlkasmdlkasmdcjkndscnksndcdkcnksdjcnksdnckjsdncsdnjkanckjanckjsnckjasncjkasnckjasncjkasnckdslnjcvlkjdncjsnjkasncjkasncjkasnckjasncjkasnckjsanckjsanckjasncjksancjksancjksancjkasncjasncjkasncklas;NKCNDJKVALNVJKSDANCKSCNJSNCJKSDCNKJSDNCKJANCDKNLSACNJDKCNJKNCAKJNACJKNKJANCKJSNCishan","cool1"]
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
func configureTableView() {
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 160.0
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(basicCellIdentifier) as BasicCell
    cell.titleLabel.text = items[indexPath.row]
   return cell
}


 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: you have single cell in tableview?

Comment: items is an array of 5 elements but all elements have very large number of characters.

Comment: technically tableview inherits from uiscrollview,so in your case tableview should be scrollable by default,what is the problem you are getting?

Comment: Do all 5 items are appearing in 5 different rows of table view?

Comment: Pardon me if I understand your question wrong, add some more string values to items and let us know whether it is scrollable or not

Comment: Two rows and half the this row capture the whole screen. Unable to scroll down see the other elements

Comment: add this in configureTableView and check self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)

Comment: I downloaded your project. It works fine in the simulator. When you brng it up it starts at cell 0. All the cells can be viewed by scrolling down. Be sure you are using the simulator properly if that is where your problem is. However, in your layout you have an empty scrollview. It does nothing. Delete it and the tableview works as in a standard tableview.

Answer (score 1):

I have just run your project and I think I found the problem. You are not calling the `configureTableView` method anywhere.

I made the following change:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.configureTableView()
        tableView.reloadData()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
```

The result i get is:

[image]

Hope this was the result you were trying to achieve. Let me know if you need more help.